# Angular 13+ Web App to Mobile App with Capacitor -- Issue Connecting to API

Tags: android, capacitor, mobile-application, angular13

I have an Angular 13+ web application with a PHP backend that works perfectly on browsers. I am trying to convert this application to native mobile apps (Android and iOS) using Capacitor. I have successfully converted the frontend shell to a native android app using Android Studio and Capacitor, however, the application does not appear to be able to hit my APIs. The API can be hit successfully by postman and can be hit successfully in a browser when the Angular app is bundled.

I am confused as to why my Android application would not be able to hit an API that both postman and the browser can hit. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I can supply code that calls the API in my Angular service as well as the receiving endpoint. Is there a Capacitor plugin that I should be using to make it work?

Note: Android Studio DOES have the INTERNET permission enabled.

I have tried changing my API endpoint's style (different URL link, more RESTful, etc) to no avail. I have tried turning the INTERNET permission on and off again to no avail. Nothing I seem to change allows the android studio application to hit my API.

Comment: A http protocol?

Comment: Is there something special about the http protocol that I would have to implement for android / iOS apps versus just my angular app? I thought it should all translate...

Comment: By default the http protocol is blocked on modern Android systems. You should enable clear text traffic in application tag of manifest file.

Comment: Is that done like so?

<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...
</application>

I just tested that and it doesn't seem to change anything. I also am unfamiliar with how to debug in Android Studio and find out why exactly it isn't hitting my API, or if there is another error.